# Accessing to an element through .reduce() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

I'm trying to understand how the `.reduce()` function is working.
So, we have an array of purchases, where each purchase is an object.

```
const purchases = [{"owner":"Barry","price":103},
{"owner":"Bob","price":75},
{"owner":"Bob","price":73},{"owner":"Barry","price":57},
{"owner":"Barry","price":128},
{"owner":"Bob","price":119},{"owner":"Barry","price":133},
{"owner":"Barry","price":27},
{"owner":"Barry","price":138},{"owner":"Bob","price":68},
{"owner":"Bob","price":50},
{"owner":"Barry","price":9},{"owner":"Bob","price":123},
{"owner":"Bob","price":135},
{"owner":"Barry","price":30},{"owner":"Barry","price":129},
{"owner":"Barry","price":38},
{"owner":"Bob","price":133},{"owner":"Barry","price":109},
{"owner":"Bob","price":115}]
```

I'm trying to accumulate all the purchases for Bob through .reduce() function. Here is my code:

```
let bobsTotal = purchases.reduce(el => {
  if (el["owner"] === "Barry") {return el["price"]}
})
```

I just can't get how we can access the "price" property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `Array.prototype.reduce(function, accumulator)`: you are essentially iterating a `function` over each `object` in an `array` to update an `accumulator`.

Where said `function` takes the form `(accumulator, object, index, array) => (accumulator)`.

Check out the [Mozilla documentation reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more info.

See the code below for a practical example.

```js
// Purchases.
const purchases = [
  {"owner":"Barry","price":103},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":75},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":73},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":57},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":128},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":119},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":133},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":27},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":138},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":68},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":50},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":9},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":123},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":135},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":30},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":129},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":38},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":133},
  {"owner":"Barry","price":109},
  {"owner":"Bob","price":115}
]

// Total Bob.
const totalBob = purchases.reduce((total, purchase) => {    
  if (purchase.owner == 'Bob') total += purchase.price // Owner == Bob.
  return total      
}, 0)

// Log.
console.log(totalBob)
```

Comment: *purchases for Bob* -> `return total + purchase.owner === "Bob" ? purchase.price : 0;` ...

Comment: Ahahah my bad. I didn't read the entire question. I've amended the code to return Bob's total. Thanks!